# Lambda call ALB in same subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to preface this with, I have no clue when it comes to networking so if this question seems really dumb, I apologize.

I have an AWS Lambda that calls an external system's API.  They have requested that instead of me calling their endpoint, that I setup an ALB on my side.  That ALB will then register their endpoints and manage the balancing for them.

I created an EC2 ALB and put it in the same VPC as my Lambda.  I added a SG to the ALB to allow traffic over 443 and 80.  I setup a listener rule that will forward to the target group when a specific path is included in the request.

From here, I'm not sure how I am supposed to call my ALB from my lambda.  I tried using the DNS name (http://{DNS Name}{Lisenter Rule Path}) but I get an error "Not Found for URL" with the URL mentioned earlier.

Is there something else I need to do to configure my Lambda to call the ALB?  Should I not use the DNS name for accessing it?

Comment: Tried using dns how? Any code example for that? What is the full error message?

Comment: Why do they want you to use a Load Balancer? What do you mean by "register their endpoints and manage the balancing for them"? Load Balancing from what to what? Are they saying that they have _multiple_ endpoints and they want you to distribute the load over all of them? How many requests does your Lambda function send every second? How long do the requests take to process?

Comment: @Marcin - I used the DNS Name generated by AWS when you create an ALB.  It's listed under the ARN for the ALB when I have it selected in my list of EC2 Load Balancers.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I'm not privy to their architecture (I am supposed to create the ALB and then give them access to configure it) but I believe that they have a group of EC2 instances that they want to load balance requests across.  So when I have completed my processing of the request, I need to make a request to the ALB in front of their EC2s.  My lambda (which is part of a target group, so could be lambdaS) could send many hundreds of requests/sec to the ALB that will be in front of their EC2 instances.

Comment: They should put that architecture in _their_ environment, not yours! Anyway, the Load Balancer will give you a DNS name that should resolve to a private IP address. I'd suggest starting by getting the Load Balancer configured, then test it by sending a request from an EC2 instance in the same VPC (eg `curl http://...`). Then, if that is working, modify the Lambda function to send the request to the Load Balancer. If you are having problems, check that the Load Balancer DNS name resolves to a private IP address, and show us the _exact_ error message you are receiving (and where it is appearing)